# SQL: NOT IN vs NOT EXISTS strange behavior

Tags: sql-server, exists, not-exists

In my searching for answers, I seem to only be finding explanations that cover the existence of `NULL` which is why the `NOT IN` returns 0 results. However, my scenario is exactly the opposite. I'm getting my expected results with the `NOT IN` and my `NOT EXISTS` is giving me 0. And to clarify, I have no NULLs in my sub-query. Here is my query:

```
DECLARE @EndDate DATE= CAST(CONCAT(YEAR(GETDATE()), '-', MONTH(GETDATE()), '-01') AS DATE) --First day of this month
DECLARE @StartDate DATE= DATEADD(month, -12, @EndDate) --12 months prior


SELECT Deactivated = COUNT(DISTINCT o.ClinicLocationId) 
       FROM [order].package p WITH(NOLOCK)
            INNER JOIN [order].[order] o WITH(NOLOCK) ON o.packageid = p.packageid
            INNER JOIN profile.ClinicLocationInfo cli WITH(NOLOCK) ON cli.LocationId = o.ClinicLocationId
                                                                      AND cli.FacilityType IN('CLINIC', 'HOSPITAL')
       WHERE CAST(p.ShipDTM AS DATE) >= dateadd(month,-1,@StartDate)
             AND CAST(p.ShipDTM AS DATE) < dateadd(month,-1,@EndDate)
             AND p.isshipped = 1
             AND o.IsShipped = 1
             AND ISNULL(o.iscanceled, 0) = 0
             and not exists (
             --and o.ClinicLocationId not in (
                                                SELECT DISTINCT o.ClinicLocationId 
                                                    FROM [order].package p WITH(NOLOCK)
                                                        INNER JOIN [order].[order] o WITH(NOLOCK) ON o.packageid = p.packageid
                                                        INNER JOIN profile.ClinicLocationInfo cli WITH(NOLOCK) ON cli.LocationId = o.ClinicLocationId
                                                                                                                    AND cli.FacilityType IN('CLINIC', 'HOSPITAL')
                                                    WHERE CAST(p.ShipDTM AS DATE) >= @StartDate
                                                            AND CAST(p.ShipDTM AS DATE) < dateadd(day,-1,@EndDate)
                                                            AND p.isshipped = 1
                                                            AND o.IsShipped = 1
                                                            AND ISNULL(o.iscanceled, 0) = 0
                                                )
```

For a high level overview, I'm basically trying to find the number of ID's that exist in one set that don't in the next (separated by a 12 month rolling window, offset by 1 month). But for the sake of simplicity, I've written the below that very simply illustrates the exact same symptom:

```
drop table if exists #T1, #T2

create table #T1 (id int)
create table #T2 (id int)

insert into #T1 (id)
values
(3),
(8)

insert into #T2 (id)
values
(671),
(171)

select id from #T1 where id not in (select id from #T2)
select id from #T1 where not exists (select id from #T2)
```

My expectation is that both of these would yield the same results, the contents of `#T1` (3,8) but instead, I only get those results in the second query by eliminating the `NOT`. I would assume I'm suffering from a fundamental misunderstanding of how the `EXISTS` operator works, as up until now I assumed there was no real difference aside from how the scanning occurred and NULL handling.

Where am I going wrong with my expectation?

Comment: In the simple example, the second query has a non-correlated subquery, while `IN` is a semi-join, i.e. correlated to the outer query. Stated differently, `not exists (select id from #T2)` is always false. It looks like the same thing applies to the larger query.

Comment: The two queries are very different, you have no *correlation* in your second query, it returns false if *any* row exists in `#t2`

Comment: the `not exists` would be expected to be `select id from #T1 where not exists (select * from #T2 WHERE #T2.id = #T1.id )` to get the desired correlation.

Comment: Kudos for adding the succinct example, btw.

Comment: Ok, I think that helps. Correlation is the key that I was missing. I added the `#T1.id=#T2.id` and that reverses the output, which at least makes sense now. Thank you all! Hopefully this will get me going.

Comment: Confirmed, this alleviated my issue, so now instead of using the `IN` which was a 19 second drain, I now have a 1 second query. Thanks guys!

Comment: There is so much badness in this query. In no particular order: `CAST(p.ShipDTM AS DATE) >= dateadd(month,-1,@StartDate)` unnecessary cast, as you anyway have a `date` on the right side so you can just do `p.ShipDTM >= dateadd(month,-1,@StartDate) AND p.ShipDTM < datadd(day, 1, dateadd(month,-1,@EndDate))`. Use of `NOLOCK` is a really bad idea. `IN (SELECT DISTINCT ...` makes no sense, the optimizer will probably remove the `DISTINCT` but it shouldn't be there. Same table alias in outer query and subquery is confusing.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The query shape...

```sql
and o.ClinicLocationId not in (SELECT o.ClinicLocationId ...)
```

...correlates `o.ClinicLocationId` to `o.ClinicLocationId` in the subquery.

When using `exists` you have to write a correlated subquery to get the same effect:

```sql
and not exists (SELECT o1.ClinicLocationId ...
    AND o1.ClinicLocationId = o.ClinicLocationId)
```

Note that the second query requires a different alias in the subquery.

Comment: Precisely what I figured out. I tried o=o, but quickly learned that was a fail lol so I renamed the SQ's o to o1, and did this. Works like a charm. Thanks for putting it into an official answer, surely I can't be the only one who missed this lesson :)